# Creating multiple threads C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

Im writing a program that multiplies two matrices using a variable number of threads and then compares execution time for each run. The user specifies the maximum number of threads to use and then the program does the multiplication with 1 thread, again with 2, 3, 4....up to max_threads (we don't have to worry about max_threads being more than 8). So whats the best way to create the threads for each run? Here's my best shot in the dark.

EDIT: I have to use pthread.

```
//Ive already called multiplyMatrices for the single thread run. Start with 2 threads.
for (int h=2; h <= max_threads; h++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {   
        pthread_create(thr_id[i],NULL, multiplyMatrices, i);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(thr_id[i],NULL);
    }
}
```

The code for multiplyMatrices is below.

```
void* multiplyMatrices(void* val)
{    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i = i*val)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < p; j++)
    {
            c[i][j] = 0;
            for(int k = 0; k < m; k++)
        {
                c[i][j] += matrix_A[i][k] * matrix_B[k][j];
            }
        }
    val++;
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest looking into OpenMP myself. And when you run, make sure the matrices are nice and big or you won't see much improvement at all.

Comment: why are you computing i*val? You realize you multiply i by an **address**, right?

Comment: So what is the problem with this code? Is is not working? Are you getting errors?

Comment: Cant use OpenMP. I'm doing i*val so that each thread only handles certain rows making it parallelizable (4 threads -> thread 0 does rows 0,4,8,12... thread 1 does rows 1,5,9,13....). Dunno if there are problems with the code as I haven't compiled yet. Im just asking if this is the correct way to do something like this.

Comment: Sounds like a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

It is `C++` use [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) + [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
std::vector<std::thread > thread_pool;
thread_pool.reserve(h);
void* someData;
for(int i = 0; i < h; i++)
{   
    thread_pool.push_back(std::thread(std::bind(multiplyMatrices, someData)));
}
```

Comment: Since `std::thread` is (to my knowledge) a move-only resource management type anyway, where is the need for a `std::unique_ptr` and dynamic memory allocation here?

Comment: By the way, there's no need for `std::move` here, since temporaries are rvalues anyway.

Comment: `std::bind` is not needed here and you could even use `emplace_back` directly

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem I see with your code is how you're passing the data to the thread function. The data should be passed as a pointer. The following should work better:

```
for (int h=2; h <= max_threads; h++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {   
        // Notice Im passing a pointer to i here.
        // Since i may go out of scope, and its value could change before the
        // thread is started and multiplyMatrices() is called, this could be
        // risky. Consider using an array/vector defined before these for
        // loops to avoid this problem.
        pthread_create(thr_id[i],NULL, multiplyMatrices, &i);
        ...

void* multiplyMatrices(void* valPtr)
{    
    int val = *((int*) valPtr);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i = i*val)
    {
       ...
```